# Local host is not accessed by external devices

Tags: apache, local

This is the first time that I am dealing with LANs and I am not sure why I am having that problem. 
I am trying to establish a local network so I can have access its files through any device that is connected. I have successfully installed apache2 on a Ubuntu 16.04 xenial, and serve an .html file from that device. I can access my html when I type my IP address or 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

However, when I am trying to access the document using my IP address from another device that is connected at the same network, the html file is not loaded. I looked on the configuration file of my apache server and is not constrained to only listen a particular IP address. It listens on 0.0.0.0:80 address, which makes it accessible from any device.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your patience

Comment: Thats why its called local host, its only accessible by your local machine, not by external devices. Try using the network adress (usually 192.168.xx.xx) to access the device from within your private network.

Comment: I am not getting any similar network address. When i type ifconfig in the terminal take the following addresses: inet addr: 10.128.44.236 P-t-P:10.128.44.236  Mask:255.255.240.0

Comment: In this case, 10.128.44.236 is (probably) the network adress. Try accessing this adress from within your local network. Also, if the server is not hosted on a standard port, you might also have to provide the port on which the application is running.

Comment: I tried to access it using 10.128.44.236 and 10.128.44.236:80, but it didn't changed anything. Using the command sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN, which I found on that (https://askubuntu.com/questions/9368/how-can-i-see-what-ports-are-open-on-my-machine ) link, I determined that my apache is working on port 80.

Comment: Assuming 10.128.44.236 is the address of the system running Apache, try these from another system on the same LAN: 1- ping 10.128.44.236  2- telnet 10.128.44.236 80  this should connect  3- if nothing works, ensure your other system is on the same IP range (like it's address is 10.128.44.SOMETHING)  4- check ip tables of other firewall software on you server, ensure port 80 is allowed to receive traffic